# Referencing a module in the same file as it's declaration

Tags: typescript

I have the following issue:

The TypeScript declarations for the Pixi library exist but seem to be broken. Firstly, they start with

```
declare module PIXI
```

instead of

```
declare module "PIXI"
```

I'm not sure if this is wrong but all the other delcarations (for node, socket.io, etc.) seem to use strings for names. When I change it to a string it works but encounters an error later. Outside of that PIXI module there this:

```
declare function requestAnimFrame( animate: PIXI.IBasicCallback );
```

Now because I changed PIXI to a string (I assume), it says that the variable PIXI doesn't contain a type named IBasicCallback. The module does export that type, but it's just not available outside of it. Outside of the declaration file, in my code, I can use PIXI.IBasicCallback just fine, but inside the same file it's not recognized.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I should note that if I don't change PIXI to "PIXI", my require code can't find the module: 
import PIXI = require("PIXI");

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between internal and external modules (CommonJS/NodeJS,AMD/RequireJS). `"SomeThing"` is used for external modules. Whereas a internal modules are declared without a string.

```
// Declare a external module 
declare module "Foo"{
    var foo:number; 
    export = foo;
}
// Use 
import a = require("Foo");


// Declare an internal module 
declare module Boo{
    export var boo:string;
}
// usage
var  b = Boo.boo;
```

I also did a video on the subject : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Answer (score 0):

It appears that some modules require you to do stuff like

```
declare module "pixi" {
    exports = PIXI;
}
```

manually. Adding that to be bottom of the delcaration (and not changing the original declaration to a string) works.